# Nltk lemmatizers do not recognize the plural form of chemical names

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

So, I must admit, I'm a total noob in nlp, and I have no idea whatsoever about nltk, I'm just trying to use a legacy code left by the previous developer. I need to lemmatize words, mostly from chemical and biotech publications. I generally use WordNetLemmatizer. Most of the time it works.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize('cats')
```

returns cat.

But then I try

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize('dehydrogenases')
```

it returns 'dehydrogenases'. I want it to return 'dehydrogenase'. How can I do that?

Comment: If you can switch to [Lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) you'll probably have better luck.  It does a better job of handling out of dictionary words because it can look at the letter pattern and choose an appropriate rule to remove the suffix.  And if you really need top accuracy, it's based on the NIH's SPECIALIST Lexicon which contains a lot of biomedical terms.  The released version of the library has many of these removed but the software could be modified to include all the biomed terms.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

If you install `nltk` as a module and then use the following code to initialize the WordNetLemmatizer:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
```

You are likely to get a `LookupError` that says:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')

  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/
```

**Reason**

The lemmatizer that you initalized is based on [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Quoting the documentation of WordNet:

> WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs,
>   adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms
>   (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept. Synsets are interlinked
>   by means of conceptual-semantic and lexical relations. The resulting
>   network of meaningfully related words and concepts can be navigated
>   with the browser. WordNet is also freely and publicly available for
>   download. WordNet's structure makes it a useful tool for computational
>   linguistics and natural language processing.

Basically, it does not have all the words in the English dictionary to lemmatize. So, while it works for the word cats, it may not work for other words that aren't in the lexical database of WordNet.

I hope this helps.